# Why do I need prototype here?

Tags: javascript, prototype

can someone explain what's the difference between this:

```
<script>
function Employee() {
  this.name = "serj";

}

function Manager() {
 Employee.call(this);
  this.dept = "general";
}

var jim = new Manager;
console.log(jim.name); //serj
</script>
```

And this:

```
<script>
function Employee() {
  this.name = "serj";
}

Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.dept = "general";
}

var jim = new Manager;
console.log(jim.name); //serj
</script>
```

So the question is why should I create a prototype?If manager calls employee and all works fine?

Comment: The prototype is useless here because the class `Employee` is useless in itself. You will almost never see such a pointless class definition in the real world. Add at least one method to it and you'll consider the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the constructor function for `Employee` will run all the code *that is inside that function*. It won't perform all the side effects (i.e. creating a new object, assigning it to `this` and making it an instance of `Employee` … and you wouldn't want it to because you want it to be an instance of `Manager`).